# Why does observable not produce any element

Tags: .net-core, scope, system.reactive, iasyncenumerable

I am wondering why my `Observable` does not produce any element when i am not awaiting its source which is an `IAsyncEnumerable`.I am using a `Select` over the `Observable`, and nothing comes out of it , my code does not execute.

```cs
public async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetAsyncEnumerable()
{
    int i=0;
    while(true)
    {
       await Task.Delay(1000);
       yield return i++;
    }
}
public async Task Run()
{
    IAsyncEnumerable<int> enumerable=GetAsyncEnumerable().ToObservable();

    await foreach(var elem in enumerable)
    {
            Console.WriteLine(elem);
    }
}
```

In the above example , the code works and is called while below there is nothing coming out.

```cs
public async Task RunObs()
{
    IAsyncEnumerable<int> enumerable=GetAsyncEnumerable().ToObservable();
    IObservable<int> inputObs = enumerable.ToObservable();
    var outputObs = inputObs
                    .Select(elem=>
                    { 
                        Console.WriteLine(elem); //does not execute
                        return elem;
                    });
}
```

Do I need to store somewhere the reference to this observable, or how should one do this?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] for your `Run` method?

Comment: I have edited.Basically the code with the observable that runs in the `Select` does not get executed.

Comment: Your code gives me this error, in the first line inside the `Run()`: `Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IObservable<int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<int>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: Where are you getting the `.ToObservable()` from?

Comment: I'm getting it from the package `System.Linq.Async`

Answer (score 1):

The observable does not produce any elements, because you need to subscribe to it to it to get them.

When you `await` an observable you implicitly subscribe to the observable, the method will return when the observable completes or errors. If it completes you will receive the last value produced.

```cs
    var outputObs = await GetAsyncEnumerable()
                    .ToObservable()
                    .Select(elem =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(elem); 
                        return elem;
                    })
                    .Take(5);
    Console.WriteLine(outputObs);
```

will output
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4 on the console(each number on different lines of course)

This will also cause the observable to produce output:

```cs
    GetAsyncEnumerable()
                    .ToObservable()
                    .Take(5)
                    .Subscribe(elem =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(elem);                        
                    });
```

0, 1, 2, 3, 4

Because now you also subsribed to the observable.
Hope it makes sense?